# Value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \exp(-bn^a)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

What is the value of 
$$
S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \exp(-bn^a)
$$
where $a>0$ and $b>0$?

I know that 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-bx^a) \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{ab^{1/a}}\Gamma(1/a)
$$
but cannot find an appropriate expression for the sum. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $ S = \displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \exp \left( -bx^a \right) $?

Comment: Yes, sorry will edit it in a sec. Tnx

Comment: Done for you, @Kostya.

Comment: Is $b>0$?. If so, this is a geometric series. Otherwise, it is divergent, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, $b>0$, but i don't see how you can reduce it to a geometric series

Comment: My mistake. Didn't realize you were summing over $x$ rather than $b$. Haven't had coffee yet. ;)

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway for looking.

Answer (score 2):

For $a=0$, it diverges. For $a=1$, we have a geometric series. For $a=2$, we have the [elliptic theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). Otherwise, there are no other known closed forms.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to prove that S is at least finite for arbitrary $a>0$?

Comment: @Kostya : yes: compare $e^{-n^a}$ with $n^{-1-a}$. Repetitive application of L'Hopital's rule makes this fairly straightforward.

Comment: @Kijang: Thanks for your reply, but i don't see why $e^{-n^a}$ and $n^{-1-a}$ form an undetermined form

Comment: as n goes to infinity they both approach 0.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Euler-MacLaurin Sum Formula to get an approximate solution.

$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n f(i)=\int_m^{n}f(x)dx+B_1(f(n)-f(m))+\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2‌​k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(m)\right)+R\tag{1}$$

Setting $m=0,f(n)=\exp(-bn^a)$, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)=\int_0^{n}f(x)dx+B_1(f(n)-f(0))+\sum_{k=1}^p\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2‌​k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(0)\right)+R\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to prove that S is at least finite for arbitrary $a>0$?

Comment: $S =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \exp(-bn^a)$. When $n\to\infty$,$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\approx\exp(-b(a/n))\approx 1-ba/n$. So I think that the series converges.

Comment: Sorry, don't see this, i think $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\approx \exp{(-ban^{a-1})}$

Comment: You are right!!

Answer (score 1):

Define $S(b)$ the function
$$S(b)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm e^{-bn^a}$$
and consider its Mellin transform
$$\hat S(z)=\int_0^\infty S(b)b^{z-1}\,\mathrm db=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n^a)^{-z}\Gamma(z)=\zeta(az)\Gamma(z)$$
Now looking up in the table of Mellin transforms (for instance Erdélyi, *Table of integral transforms* volume 1), I can only found the inverse Mellin transform in tha case $a=1$ and $a=2$. So I can't give any full answer, but it seems that the functions for different values of $a$ have not yet been given a name.